# How to set the SentMail Folder as Folder?

Tags: vba, outlook

I want to export the SentMail folder of an additional Mailbox.

I can use `olFolderInbox as Folder` with `GetSharedDefaultFolder` but not `olFolderSentMail`.

I get

> Runtime Error -2147024809 (80070057)

```vb
Dim AttachCount As Long
Dim AttachDtl() As String
Dim ExcelWkBk As Excel.Workbook
Dim FileName As String
Dim FolderTgt As MAPIFolder
Dim HtmlBody As String
Dim InterestingItem As Boolean
Dim InxAttach As Long
Dim InxItemCrnt As Long
Dim PathName As String
Dim ReceivedTime As Date
Dim RowCrnt As Long
Dim SenderEmailAddress As String
Dim SenderName As String
Dim Subject As String
Dim TextBody As String
Dim xlApp As Excel.Application
Dim objNS As NameSpace

Dim Item As Object
Dim varOutput() As Variant
Dim lngcount As Long

Dim olNs As Outlook.NameSpace
Dim olRecip As Outlook.Recipient
Dim SubFolder As Object

Set olNs = Application.GetNamespace("MAPI")
Set olRecip = olNs.CreateRecipient("test@mailbox.de") '// Owner's Name or email address
Set FolderTgt = olNs.GetSharedDefaultFolder(olRecip, olFolderSentMail)
'  Set SubFolder = ShareInbox.Folders("Temp") 'Change this line to specify folder
```

Comment: Which line of code throws the error? See [mcve]. What is the exact error message?

Comment: This ist the Line with the failure 

 Set FolderTgt = olNs.GetSharedDefaultFolder(olRecip, olFolderSentMail)


The Message: Runtime Error -2147024809 (80070057)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sometimes you have to work around the bugs in Outlook VBA.

```vb
Set FolderTgt = olNs.GetSharedDefaultFolder(olRecip, olFolderInbox)
    
Set FolderTgt = FolderTgt.Parent
    
Set FolderTgt = FolderTgt.folders("Sent Items")
'or
' Set FolderTgt = FolderTgt.folders("Sent")
```